# Flex combobox drop down halted when i select one item and show alert

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Here is my code.
I run this code on change event.

```
for(var i:uint =0; i< model.medicalHistoryDTOListByPatient.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(formatDateTime.format(model.medicalHistoryDTOListByPatient[i].VisitDate) == formatDateTime.format(id_VisitDatesCombo.selectedItem.VisitDate) )
                        {
                            Alert.show('Record already exsist against this Visit', 'Please select another date ');
                            id_HistoryView.enabled = false;
                            break;
                        }else{
                            if(model.CHistoryAssociatedVisit != null)
                            {
                                model.CHistoryAssociatedVisit.VisitDate = id_VisitDatesCombo.selectedItem.VisitDate;
                                model.CHistoryAssociatedVisit.ID        = id_VisitDatesCombo.selectedItem.VisitId;
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

When if condition is matched and alert is popup then drop down still open and alert is shown.

How i close dropdownlist when i select one of item from Drop-down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dropDownList.closeDropDown()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/DropDownListBase.html#closeDropDown%28%29) to manually force the drop down list to close.  This should also work for the Flex Spark ComboBox.

The MX ComboBox has a [close](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#close%28%29) method you can use.

Comment: for the sack of quick fix I use calllater(methodname) and show the alert in that method.

Comment: Something else must be going on with your code.  Can you provide a full runnable sample?